# Does this function satisfy "Intermediate Value Property"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Although this problem may look easy, but I am very much confused over this. 
Consider the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}(1-x)/|x|, & x\neq 0\\1, & x=0\end{cases}$$

Does $f$ satisfy the Intermediate Value Property on $[-2,2]$?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind and tell us what you've tried? You know that the intermediate value property holds for continuous functions and that your $f$ is continuous except for one point?

Comment: Graphing the function would be a good first step; the picture leads fairly easily to counterexamples like the one that tetori gives.

Comment: @Dirk: It's worth noting that, while continuous functions satisfy the IVP, not all functions satisfying the IVP are continuous. In fact there are functions (such as [Conway's Base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function)) satisfying IVP that are everywhere discontinuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ does not satisfy intermediate value property. By definition $f(1/4)=3$. If $f$ satisfy IVP, then there is $0<a<1/4$ s.t. $f(a)=2$. But $f(x)=1/x-1$ for $x>0$ and $1/x-1> 3$ if $0<x<1/4$.

Comment: thanks a lot...i missed that small point